# What are all the hardwares/sensors can be accessed through React-Native without Third-Party libraries?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

At least on Android, Can I access Camera, Mic, Fingerprint sensor without any third party libraries help? How other Major Brands are doing it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GPS location using navigator object.